# Sorting array into table by first two characters

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

Ok, so  I have an array like this:

```
['0157', 
'0234', 
'0467', 
'0164', 
'0363', 
'0341', 
'0179', 
...]
```

And I need to sort the array into table (2D array) like this one:

```
0157|0234|0326|0467
0164|    |0341|
0179|    |    |
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: what is the criteria? is it the 2nd string character value? what did you try? show us some code you wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
import itertools
data = ['0157', '0234', '0467', '0164', '0363', '0341', '0179']
output = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(data), lambda x: x[:2]):
    output.append(list(group))
print output
```

where `groupby` makes groups by first two chars `x[:2]`.

The output is

```
[['0157', '0164', '0179'], ['0234'], ['0341', '0363'], ['0467']]
```

For more information of `groupby`, check out [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).